# WebView in Dialog gives exception on enabling Plugins in android

Tags: android-webview

I have followed example program given in below link for placing WebView in Dialog.
http://www.41post.com/4673/programming/android-creating-a-webview-dialog

Application is working perfectly fine. But if I enable plugins (setPlauginsEnabled(true)); application gives exception.
Issue exists only for websites with flash content.

Below is the part of code,
        *

```
        webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        //Set the user agent
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("AndroidWebView");
        //Clear the cache
        webView.clearCache(true);
        //Make the webview load the specified URL
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.coca-cola.com/en/index.html");
```

*

Below is the code trace,

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1868): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1868): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
E/AndroidRuntime( 1868):        at com.adobe.flashplayer.FlashPaintSurface.getBrowserActivity(FlashPaintSurface.java:650)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1868):        at com.adobe.flashplayer.FlashPaintSurface$2.surfaceCreated(FlashPaintSurface.java:208)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1868):        at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:533)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1868):        at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:81)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1868):        at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:169)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1868):        at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:590)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1868):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1617)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1868):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2446)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1868):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1868):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1868):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1868):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1868):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1868):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1868):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1868):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager( 1117):   Force finishing activity fortyonepost.com.webviewdialog/.WebViewDialogActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved;

Create FrameLayout inside WebViewDialog.xml & add WebView in to FrameLayout.

```
webView = new WebView(this);
wrapper = (FrameLayout)webViewDialog.findViewById(R.id.webview_wrapper);
wrapper.addView(webView);
```

If WebView is attached to WebView layout, flash plugin will create problems.